# Как работать с SAXParser ?

Tags: xml, sax, java

У меня есть такой XML Документ

```
<campaign id = '1'>
<numberOfHits> 1000 </numberOfHits>
<Region>
    <id> region1 </id>
    <id> region2 </id>         
</Region>
<budget> 500 </budget>
<intervalOfTime> 5 </intervalOfTime>
<Site>
    <siteId> 1 </siteId>
</Site>
</campaign>
```

Мне нужно его распарсить и внести данные в объект типа Campaign

```
public class Campaign {

    private int compaignId;
    private Target target;
    private int numberOfHits;
    private double budget;
    private Period intervalOfTime;
    private ArrayList<Site> sites;

    //-----===== getter и setter всех полей ====-----
}
```

А вот класс регион:
    public class Region {

```
static enum region{
    region1("1"),
    region2("2"),
    region3("3"),
    region4("4"),
    region5("5"),
    region6("6"),
    region7("7"),
    region8("8"),
    region9("9"),
    regoin10("10");

    private String value;

    region(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

}

Начал писать SAXParser и столкнулся с несовпадением типов:

```
if (thisElement.equals("region")) {
   doc.setNumberOfHits(new String(ch, start, length));
}
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы после парсинга у меня был ArrayList<Region>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Преобразовать строку в int](http://www.javadb.com/convert-a-string-to-int):

```
try {
    iValue = Integer.parseInt(sValue);
}
catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    System.out.println("Ошибка!");
}
```

Comment: а как в моем коде исправить это?

Comment: Исправить что? Во-первых, непонятно, что такое doc.setNumberOfHits. Во-вторых, изначально вроде хотелось получить Integer, а после редакции вопроса появился какой-то region(String), никак не связанный с приведённым кодом вообще. Вы уж определитесь, и напишите, что именно не получается.

Comment: мне нужно достать из хml файла список регионов и запихнуть их в ArrayList. 
Как это сделать?